# Which editing options is the best on sys admin application

Tags: user-behavior, design-patterns, edit

I m testing new consept of dashboard aplication.

Does anyone know which approach is better Alt 1 or Alt2 and if you can argue through some examples on Web  / or give me some advice?

What is simpliest way for user?  to edit and save work directly in component or to save work in footer (group of CTA) ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can conduct a **usability-testing** session with at least 3 end users as participant (if possible, 10). Keep in mind that the vision of this session will be:

1. Uncover problems in the design
2. Discover opportunities to improve the design
3. Learn about user's behavior and preferences

As a facilitator, you need to present the goal of the product/system you are designing for to the participants. Be alert not to ask leading questions before giving task, like "do you think the single-component edit option is useful?". Leave the participant with the prototype/wireframe and observe their behavior carefully.

As you asked for some advice, I would specially mention again the point of **not asking leading questions** so that participants don't get biased.

Remember, your participants are your end users. By observing the session, you can uncover many opportunities with that "Edit and save" option.

Good luck to your dashboard design!

Answer (score 0):

Alt 1 & Alt 2 can be useful in different scenarios.
Alt 1 approach can be used if user needs to edit each component separately and update as per requirement.
Alt 2 approach can be used if users need to edit/update most of the  components frequently. This would save few clicks but managing that many components together is big task for users.

Comment: Thanks @Yobuddy ! Do you think is it smart to use both options in one page or I need to choose one of these two? What is best practise here?

Comment: @Bane Use only one option here which is best for your users and scenario, thanks!